# This is very likely to create a memory leak in tomcat 7.0.x

Tags: spring, tomcat, memory-leaks, activemq-classic

I am getting "This is very likely to create a memory leak" error time to time. Once I get the error I, could not connect with activeMQ. We have noticed this error recently.Here is the trace:

```
    27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 1: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 2: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [ActiveMQ Scheduler] but has failed to stop it. This is very
likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 3: ProducerTemplate] but has failed to stop it.
This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 4: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 5: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 6: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 7: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 8: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 9: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 10: ActiveMQComponent] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 11: ProducerTemplate] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 12: ProducerTemplate] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [Camel thread 13: ProducerTemplate] but has failed to stop
it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
27-Feb-2012 08:27:55 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/Webapp] appears to have started a
thread named [ActiveMQ Connection Worker:
tcp://activeMQhost.localnet/192.168.0.15:61616] but has failed to stop it.
This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

spring bean

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">       
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${url}" /> 
</bean>
```

${url} is set to

```
tcp://activeMQhost.localnet/192.168.0.15:61616?keepAlive=true&trace=true
```

I am trying to connect with activeMQ from one machine to another machine. For example, a Webapp running on **machine1** and activeMQ running on **activeMQhost**. Some times, the thread could not close for some reason. You can find out the connection url in end of the trace:

```
tcp://activeMQhost.localnet/192.168.0.15:61616
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try specifying the `destory-method` for your connection factory bean (typically this 'stop' for ActiveMQ, not sure about the camel version).

```
<bean id="..." class="..." destroy-method="stop">
  ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using the failover transport instead...its more robust even for a single broker connection

http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Comment: We can not use another broker url now. I just wondering. This error coming after 3 or 4 hours only. do you think , connection closing for some reason?

Comment: what version of AMQ? are you using a connection pool? the failover transport is the way to go...

Comment: ActiveMQ-5.5.1 latest version. Before we used older version. recently we upgraded to latest one.

Comment: from spring i am passing only broker url like.                 ' <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${url}" />
 </bean>'                                                                   here url = tcp://activeMQhost.localnet/192.168.0.15:61616?keepAlive=true&trace=true